# Rubocop and Style/IndentationConsistency with rails enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I am using rubocop to a rails 5 project and I've added to my `.rubocop.yml` this:

```
Rails:
  Enabled: true
```

I noticed however that a rule (`Style/IndentationConsistency`) was failing and I had to explicitly add it like this:

```
Style/IndentationConsistency:
  EnforcedStyle: rails
```

Is it ok to happen or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Would you might to post an code example that the cop complained about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this is ok to happen. Not everyone is using this style in Rails projects. It's just the style used the Rails codebase itself. So if you need the rails codebase indentation you have to explicitly put both of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add Rails: Enabled: true, you will need to add the Rails individual configurations like (Rails Action Filter, FindEach, FindBy).

Please refer Rails configurations as given below.
You can also this this link(https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml)

```
  Rails/ActionFilter:
      EnforcedStyle: action
      SupportedStyles:
          - action
          - filter
      Include:
          - app/controllers/**/*.rb

  Rails/Date:
      # The value `strict` disallows usage of `Date.today`, `Date.current`,
      # `Date#to_time` etc.
      # The value `flexible` allows usage of `Date.current`, `Date.yesterday`, etc
      # (but not `Date.today`) which are overridden by ActiveSupport to handle current
      # time zone.
      EnforcedStyle: flexible
      SupportedStyles:
          - strict
          - flexible

  Rails/Exit:
      Include:
          - app/**/*.rb
          - config/**/*.rb
          - lib/**/*.rb
      Exclude:
          - lib/**/*.rake

  Rails/FindBy:
      Include:
          - app/models/**/*.rb

  Rails/FindEach:
      Include:
          - app/models/**/*.rb

  Rails/HasAndBelongsToMany:
      Include:
          - app/models/**/*.rb
```